# can not connect to oracle database using PHP 7.0.13 - OCI Connect issue

Tags: php, oracle, dll, xampp, oci8

I just installed xampp v3.2.2 on my pc. I want to create connection string to oracle using php. when i start Apache on xampp, always show popup window "the procedure entry point OCIstmtGetNextResult could not be located in the dynamic link library OCI.dll".

what should i do? thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Followed the articale:

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database

2. Add the missing files in apache/bin folder
   Add oci.dll, oraociei12.dll, and oraons.dll to apache/bin folder. Replace the existing one

Comment: I got the same error and this works. But I didn't have those files before in my apache/bin.
It also seems to depend on the client version. Some weeks ago it worked for me, but I didn't update my Apache/PHP. But I updated the Oracle client.
It is a little bit silly that you get that error message for the PHP extension dll and not for the Oracle dll.

Comment: I believe there is some reasons that apache didn't loading those needed files into the latest version...
I guess if the error occurs again after the apache being updated, it should be there is some files are missing...
I also feeling angry about spending almost a week to figure out what that happens to me...

Answer (score 0):

You probably enabled 

`extension=php_oci8.dll`

but only have the Oracle 11g libraries

Try enabling this instead

`extension=php_oci8_11g.dll`

Don't enable both - they do the same thing but have different dependencies.

Comment: Can you give more information - what you have tried and what the results were?